# When mutableStateOf is updated recomposition does not get occurred

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, compose-recomposition

I have basic composable as in the following:

```
var timer by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        Column {
            Text(text = timer.toString())
            Button(onClick = { timer++ }) {
                Text(text = "Add")
            }
        }
```

When button is clicked, internal state which is timer will be increased by one and since it has been used in the Text component, recomposition will be occurred. But if I have LazyColumn instead of Column as in the following:

```
var timer by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        LazyColumn {
            item(contentType = "timer") {
                Text(text = timer.toString())
            }
            item {
                Button(onClick = { timer++ }) {
                    Text(text = "Add")
                }
            }
        }
```

Recomposition does not occur, Do not we expect it to be recomposed since the state has been changed?

Comment: You may be confused how I check if recomposition is occurred. So, I have created SideEffect and I have another counter which was updated inside the SideEffect

Comment: You should explain better what is your issue. Your code works, and when you click the `Button`, the `Text` is updated with the new value.Other functions that don't depend on the value are not recomposed.

Comment: I think I found the problem. But before that I can explain the issue again. The code block I provided above is composable function. Furthermore, I have `SideEffect` after `LazyColumn` and `SideEffect` will run after every successful recomposition. When I click the button, recomposition must happen to update the value of `Text` component and which happens. But the code block of `SideEffect` does not trigger.

Comment: I think I know what it is happening. The definition of `SideEffect` is not clear. It says it is called after every successful recomposition but in my case recomposition happens on the scope of the first item of `LazyColumn` but my `SideEffect` is on the scope of my composable function. That's why in that scope, recomposition does not happen and SideEffect will not be triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a State is read it triggers recomposition in nearest scope.

First example:

```
    var timer by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    SideEffect {
        Log.i("info", "xxxx")
    }

    LogCompositions("JetpackCompose.app", "Composable scope")

    LazyColumn {

        item(contentType = "timer") {
            LogCompositions("JetpackCompose.app", "Item Text Scope")
            Text(text = timer.toString())
        }
        item {
            LogCompositions("JetpackCompose.app", "Item Button Scope")
            Button(onClick = { timer++ }) {
                LogCompositions("JetpackCompose.app", "Button Scope")
                Text(text = "Add")
            }
        }
    }
```

When the screen is displayed you can find:

```
Compositions: Composable scope 0
Compositions: Item Text Scope 0
Compositions: Item Button Scope 0
Compositions: Button Scope 0
I  xxxx
```

When the `Button` "Add" is clicked only the item with the Text is recomposed.

```
Compositions: Item Text Scope 1
```

It happens because it recompose the scope that are reading the values that changes: `Text(text = timer.toString())`.

Using a `Column` instead of a `LazyColumn`:

```
    var timer by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    SideEffect {
        Log.i("info", "xxxx")
    }
    LogCompositions("JetpackCompose.app", "Composable scope")
    Column {

        LogCompositions("JetpackCompose.app", "Column Scope")
        Text(text = timer.toString())

        Button(onClick = { timer++ }) {
            LogCompositions("JetpackCompose.app", "Button Scope")
            Text(text = "Add")
        }
    }
```

When the screen is diplayed:

```
Compositions: Composable scope 0
Compositions: Column Scope 0
Compositions: Button Scope 0
I  xxxx
```

When the `Button` "Add" is clicked all the composable is recomposed:

```
Compositions: Composable scope 1
Compositions: Column Scope 1
I  xxxx
```

Also in this case it happens because it recompose the scope that are reading the values that changes: `Text(text = timer.toString())`.
The scope is a function that is not marked with inline and returns Unit.
The `Column` is an inline function and it means that Column doesn't have an own recompose scopes.

---

To log composition use this composable:

```
class Ref(var value: Int)

// Note the inline function below which ensures that this function is essentially
// copied at the call site to ensure that its logging only recompositions from the
// original call site.
@Composable
inline fun LogCompositions(tag: String, msg: String) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        val ref = remember { Ref(0) }
        SideEffect { ref.value++ }
        Log.d(tag, "Compositions: $msg ${ref.value}")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what do you mean by saying Recomposition does not occur. The text is updating in both peace of code you have in the question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).